# Ghost Blogs - Author Invite Email

Tags: nodemailer, ghost-blog

I am getting this error with every config possible, I am using Apache server and proxy to access the blogs. My blog is at example_site.in/new/blogs

Here is my ghost blogs config

```
{
  "url": "https://example_site.in/new/blogs",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "admin",
      "password": "<DB Pass>",
      "database": "<DB name>"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "SMTP",
    "options": {
      "host": "smtp.zoho.com",
      "port": 587,
      "secureConnection": false,
      "auth": {
        "user": "<email>",
            "pass": "<pass>"
          }
        }
      },
      "logging": {
        "transports": [
          "file",
          "stdout"
        ]
      },
      "process": "systemd",
      "paths": {
        "contentPath": "/var/www/html/example_blogs/content"
      }
    }
```

I am getting errors such as "ssl version error","relay errors" and "greetings not received" with different configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

Added in the mail config

```
"from":"<email>"//same as host
```

And it's working,

*I have tried to add name with a separate email like "from":"example name ", But it's not working for me.*